# Nested class object with Spring data MongoDb aggregation returns null field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I have an issue problem with the inclusion of nested class in the aggregation.

This is a preview of the json document in my collection :

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "typeApp": "API",
    "name": "name",
    "versionNum": "1",
    "release": {
        "author": "name",       
        //some other data
    }
}
```

The document java class :

```
@Document(collection = "myClassExamples")
public class MyClassExampleDocument {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String typeApp;
    private String name;
    private String versionNum;
    private Release release;
  
    public static class Release {        
        private String author;
        //Other fields...
    }
   }
```

I am trying to build a query, to find the last documents group by a given *typeApp* in parameter, and sort by *versionNum DESC* to get the new one by *typeApp*.

I started with an easier query, a simple group by *typeApp* :

```
 Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "versionNum"),
                Aggregation.group("typeApp"),
                project(MyClassExampleDocument.class)
        )
```

The query returns a list of *MyClassExampleDocument*, with all fields with null values except for the *id* which is populated with the *typeApp*.

Do you know how to build the aggregation in order to get the entire object, as stored in my collection ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like following

```
public List<MyClassExampleDocument> test() {

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(        
        sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "versionNum"),
        group("typeApp").first("$$ROOT").as("data")
        replaceRoot("data")

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(MyClassExampleDocument.class), MyClassExampleDocument.class).getMappedResults();

}
```

here is the aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { versionNum: -1 } },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$typeApp",
      "data": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0UVRZPTIvk1)**

Note : The java code was not tested, it was implemented based on working mongo script